Frustrating indefinite integral
The authors in this paper state, without proof, the following indefinite integral relation:
$$\int\frac{\exp(ir_0)}{r_0}\frac{\rho}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\frac{\exp(ir)}{r}\right)\text{d}\rho = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\exp(i(r_0+r))}{r_0+r}$$
where $r^2=\rho^2+z^2$ and $r_0^2=\rho^2+z_0^2$ and $\rho\geq0$ and $z,z_0\in\mathbb{R}$ are nonzero. I've tried several different methods of proving the equation over the years, but nothing has worked so far. And I've come across at least two references that cite the result and also admit their inability to compute it.
So, how do you compute this indefinite integral?
Thanks!
Note that the integrand can also be expressed as
$$\frac{\exp(ir_0)}{r_0}\frac{\exp(ir)}{r}(i - 1/r)\frac{\rho}{r} = \frac{\exp(ir_0)}{r_0}\frac{\partial}{\partial \rho}\left(\frac{\exp(ir)}{r}\right)$$

Its trivial by replacing  $\rho \to \sqrt{r^2-z^2}$ and $d\rho \to \frac{r dr}{\sqrt{r^2-z^2}}$, but the $r+r_0$ in the denominators is a $r*r_0$

After substitution I get $\int \frac{e^{i\sqrt{r^2-z^2+z_0^2}}}{\sqrt{r^2-z^2+z_0^2}} \frac{e^{ir}}{r} (i-1/r) dr$. How do you compute that?

Evaluating the integrand
$$\frac{\rho e^{i r_0}\cdot\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\frac{e^{i r}}{r}}{r r_0}=\frac{i \rho (r+i) e^{i (r+r_0)}}{r^3 r_0}$$
We substitute $r_0\to\sqrt{r^2-z^2+z_0^2}$
$$\left.\frac{i \rho  (r+i) e^{i (r+r_0)}}{r^3 r_0}\right\rvert_{r_0\to\sqrt{r^2-z^2+z_0^2}}=\frac{i \rho  (r+i) e^{i \left(\sqrt{r^2-z^2+z_0^2}+r\right)}}{r^3 \sqrt{r^2-z^2+z_0^2}}$$
With implicit differentiation of $r^2=\rho^2+z^2$ we get $d\rho= \frac{r}{\rho} dr$, hence we are able to integrate over r
$$\int \frac{i (r+i) e^{i \left(\sqrt{r^2-z^2+z_0^2}+r\right)}}{r^2 \sqrt{r^2-z^2+z_0^2}} \text{d}r=\frac{e^{i \left(\sqrt{r^2-z^2+z_0^2}+r\right)}}{r \left(\sqrt{r^2-z^2+z_0^2}+r\right)}$$
We resubstitute $\sqrt{r^2-z^2+z_0^2}\to r_0$ and finally get
$$\int \frac{e^{i r_0}}{r_0}\frac{\rho}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\frac{\exp(ir)}{r}\right)\text{d}\rho=\frac{e^{i (r+r_0)}}{r (r+r_0)}$$
